# Fixing code review remarks

Tags: phrase-usage, phrase-request, terminology

The code review is a process of inspection of a software code in order to find flaws, errors, defects etc. During a code review an inspector writes remarks about what is wrong and should be fixed.

I need to write a list of tasks I did today. Would it be correct to name one of my tasks:

> Fixing code review remarks.

Actually I was fixing my code, not the remarks themselves.

Answer (score 1):

What you were doing can be described in several ways:

- Implementing suggested changes from the code review
- Improving the code based on comments from the code review
- Applying corrections/improvements/fixes suggested in the code review

Note that reviews typically generate *comments* (or requests for changes, in more official cases). A *remark* is a statement that is not substantial or less important than the remainder of the text. See [this post in ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/300029/164776) for a longer discussion.

Comment: Thank you! I agree that what I were doing can be described like you suggested. But I'd like to come up with a concise wording. Special thanks for toyr notice about comment/remark!